# Returning An Array From Method To Main Method. Throws An Exception In The Main Method

Tags: java, arrays, exception, methods

So I am trying to create a function that generates random coordinates and stores them into an array. I created a method that created and returned an array with 2 random numbers stored in it. However when I run my program, it keeps throwing an exception in the main method. I just want store the array in the main method so I can use it in an algorithm later.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    //This initializes each coordinate used
    int[] firstCoordinate = randomCoordinates();  //This is line four where
    int[] secondCoordinate = randomCoordinates(); // the exception is thrown        

    //end of main method
}

public static int[] randomCoordinates() {
     int[] newCoordinate = new int[2];
     for (int i = 0; i < newCoordinate.length; i++) {
         newCoordinate[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1);
     }
     System.out.println("One coordinate is (" + newCoordinate[1] + ", " + newCoordinate[2] + ")");            //Exception also thrown here.
     return newCoordinate;
}
```

The exception states:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at BetterDIAZR18.randomCoordinates(BetterDIAZR18.java:21)
    at BetterDIAZR18.main(BetterDIAZR18.java:4)

Answer (score 0):

Array index starts from 0. The size of newCoordinate is 2, you cannot get element by  newCoordinate[2].
Right code is,
System.out.println("One coordinate is (" + newCoordinate[0] + ", " + newCoordinate[1] + ")");

Comment: Thank you very much. That fixed everything. Was it trying to access the data that was past the array's length? Was that why it was throwing the exception?